# Rake task for running a server in an independent thread then killing the thread when the task is complete?

Tags: ruby, multithreading, rakefile

How do I launch a thread within a `rake task` then kill the tread when the task is complete.

Essentially I am writing a `rake task` to test a jekyll site.  I would like be able to launch the server, do some other tasks and then destroy the thread when the task is complete.  Here is what I have thus far:

```
task :test_site do
  `ejekyll --server`
  `git -Xdn`
  if agree( "Clean all ignored files?")
    git -Xdf
  end
end
```

but unfortunately the only way I know of to stop the `jekyll --server` is to use `ctrl c`.  I would be happy to hear of a way to stop a `jekyll --server` in a manor which does not exit the rake task but please just comment as the question is specifically asking about threading and rake tasks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want [`Process.spawn`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Process.html#method-c-spawn), *not* a thread.  It's a new process, not a thread of execution within an existing process.  You get the PID back, so just send [`Process.kill(:QUIT, pid)`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Process.html#method-c-kill) or whatever method you want to use to kill the spawned processed.

```
pid = Process.spawn(
  "ejekyll", "--server",
  out: "/dev/null",
  err: "/dev/null"
)

# you may need to add a short sleep() here

# other stuff

Process.kill(:QUIT, pid) && Process.wait
```

If `ejekyll` has a command line option to run in the foreground, it would be better to use that, otherwise if it self-daemonizes you need to know where it stores its PID file, in order to identify and kill the daemon.